# Pyinstaller error Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type (MacOS)

Tags: python, macos, notifications, nsnotificationcenter, pyinstaller

I need to display notifications in MacOS. Simply running the script with python can display notification. But whenever I pack the script using Pyinstaller, I get the following error. Seems like Pyinstaller is having some problem with working on Mac notifications. I also tried using `pync (Python binding for terminal notifier)`. In all cases, simply running the app `python notify.py` works, but freezing the script using Pyinstaller doesn't seem to work.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/Foundation/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from CoreFoundation import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/Users/jacob/mac-notify/build/notify/out00-PYZ.pyz/CoreFoundation", line 19, in <module>
  File "/Users/jacob/mac-notify/build/notify/out00-PYZ.pyz/objc._bridgesupport", line 121, in initFrameworkWrapper
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 939, in resource_exists
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1392, in has_resource
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1447, in _has
NotImplementedError: Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type
logout
```

I am using the following Python script to display notification

```
import Foundation
import objc

NSUserNotification = objc.lookUpClass('NSUserNotification')
NSUserNotificationCenter = objc.lookUpClass('NSUserNotificationCenter')

notification = NSUserNotification.alloc().init()
notification.setTitle_("TestTitle")
notification.setInformativeText_("This is sample text")
center = NSUserNotificationCenter.defaultUserNotificationCenter()
center.deliverNotification_(notification)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problems and this is how I made it work. You need not use `Foundation` as its making the problem with Pyinstaller (Not sure why this is causing an issue) and is not used elsewhere in your code.

```
import objc

NSUserNotification = objc.lookUpClass('NSUserNotification')
NSUserNotificationCenter = objc.lookUpClass('NSUserNotificationCenter')

notification = NSUserNotification.alloc().init()
notification.setTitle_("TestTitle")
notification.setInformativeText_("This is sample text")
center = NSUserNotificationCenter.defaultUserNotificationCenter()
center.deliverNotification_(notification)
```

At this point, it may throw some error or the notification just don't show up. **Just add `CFBundleIdentifier` key into the `info.plist` file generated by pyinstaller.**